# Add class on scroll to element even when it is only partly visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've seen many examples on how to add / remove a class on scroll.
The code below works for me, but with a BUT.

I have various sections ( modules ) on one page, and as I scroll over them, the class "module-active" are added. That is great.
The issue comes in with one module that is bigger / higher than my screen, and thus the 'module-active' class are not triggered.

When I use my external screen, which is much bigger and big enough to show the whole section / module at once, it works.

How can I trigger the addClass when the section is still partly visible?

I am happy to loose the removeClass('module-active') if need be.

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.visible = function(partial) {

  var $t = $(this),
    $w = $(window),
    viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
    viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
    _top = $t.offset().top,
    _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
    compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
    compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
   return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  checkVisible();
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  checkVisible();
});

function checkVisible() {
  $('.module').each(function(i, k) {
    if ($(this).visible()) {
      $(k).addClass('module-active');
    } else {
      $(k).removeClass('module-active');
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

```
.module.module-active {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.module {
    position: relative;
    left: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s;
}
```

Comment: What about `return ((compareBottom >= viewTop) && (compareTop <= viewBottom));` ?

Comment: Or it would seem, set `partial = true`

Comment: @freedomn-m Great, your first suggestion did the trick, Thank you so much!